# get the entire html from dom but exclude some elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the entire dom of a source page excluding some elements?

What's the jquery code for `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` ?

And how to remove from that code some divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery code for document.documentElement.innerHTML; can be

```
 $('Element').html()
```

here element can be a class ,id or the type of element itself such as ('.class')
('#id') or ('p') To exclude an element you can write

```
$('body').not('.exclude')
```

;where exclude is the class name of the elements which you want to exclude

Comment: just $('p').html() will get you entire html inside p tag same as ('#ele').html () will get you entire html inside the element who has id ele same as class ('.elem').html() will get the html inside the element who has class of elem .if there are more than one element with same class or same tag who have to apply $.fn.each function on it such as $('.elem').each(function(){alert($(this).html()) });